# Including boost libraries in make files

Tags: boost, makefile, linker

I'm learning Boost and am having trouble with my makes files.
Here is my basic makefile:

```
accesstimer: acctime.o btimer.o
    g++ acctime.o btimer.o -o accesstimer

acctime.o: acctime.cpp btimer.h
    g++ -c acctime.cpp 

bentimer.o: btimer.cpp btimer.h
    g++ -c btimer.cpp
```

When acctime.cpp has no boost filesystem elements in it this m,ake file works fine.
As soon as I add boost filesystem elements I obviously need to make references to the boost libray in the make file this is where I am having issues.

The following line works for a single file compilation:

```
g++ -I /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0 boosttest1.cpp -o bt1 /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt.a /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_system-gcc41-mt.a
```

Now I'm trying to integrate this into the make file. I've tried many based on what information I can find on the web but none are working this is my latest:

```
accesstimer: acctime.o bentimer.o
    g++ acctime.o bentimer.o -o accesstimer

acctime.o: acctime.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -c -I /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0 acctime.cpp /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt.a /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_system-gcc41-mt.a

bentimer.o: bentimer.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -c bentimer.cpp
```

Unfortunately it stlill can't find the Boost libraries, can anyone help?
thanks

Having read the advice of the people who've answered I've now got this:

```
accesstimer: acctime.o bentimer.o
    g++ -L /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0 acctime.o /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt.a /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_system-gcc41-mt.a bentimer.o -o accesstimer

acctime.o: acctime.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -c acctime.cpp 

bentimer.o: bentimer.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -c bentimer.cpp
```

But this still fails to link.

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
g++ -L /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt.a /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_system-gcc41-mt.a acctime.o  bentimer.o -o accesstimer
acctime.o: In function boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::is_basic_path<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, bool>::type boost::filesystem::exists<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&)':
acctime.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10filesystem6existsINS0_10basic_pathISsNS0_11path_traitsEEEEENS_9enable_ifINS0_13is_basic_pathIT_EEbE4typeERKS7_[boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::is_basic_path<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >, bool>::type boost::filesystem::exists<boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> >(boost::filesystem::basic_path<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::filesystem::path_traits> const&)]+0x26): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status_api(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [accesstimer] Error 1
```

Following orsogufo's advice (thanks! much appreciated) now have this:

```
accesstimer: acctime.o bentimer.o
    g++ -L/usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib -llibboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt.a -llibboost_system-gcc41-mt.a acctime.o bentimer.o -o accesstimer  

acctime.o: acctime.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -c acctime.cpp 

bentimer.o: bentimer.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -c bentimer.cpp
```

Looking better, but still can't quite find the library:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib -llibboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt.a -llibboost_system-gcc41-mt.a acctime.o bentimer.o -o accesstimer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt.a
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [accesstimer] Error 1
```

I've double checked that location and the library is definately at:
/usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt.a

STill no joy, usimg this now:

```
accesstimer: acctime.o bentimer.o
    g++  -L/usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0 -lboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt acctime.o bentimer.o -o accesstimer    

acctime.o: acctime.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -I /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0 -c acctime.cpp 

bentimer.o: bentimer.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -c bentimer.cpp
```

Getting:

```
g++  -L/usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib/ -llibboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt acctime.o bentimer.o -o accesstimer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost_filesystem-gcc41-mt
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [accesstimer] Error 1
```

It's working with this:

```
accesstimer: acctime.o bentimer.o
    g++ -L/usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem acctime.o bentimer.o -o accesstimer    

acctime.o: acctime.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -I /usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0 -c acctime.cpp 

bentimer.o: bentimer.cpp bentimer.h
    g++ -c bentimer.cpp
```

Thanks for all your help

Comment: Could you please post the error message you're getting?

Comment: When you link libraries with the -l flag, you always leave off the leading "lib". So linking libm.a is -lm, libboost is -lboost, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you link the object files to create the executable (your first makefile rule) you must pass the location of the boost libraries with the `-L` flag **and the names of the libraries with the -l flag**.

```
accesstimer: acctime.o bentimer.o
    g++ -L/usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem acctime.o bentimer.o -o accesstimer
```

where `/usr/local/boost/boost_1_39_0/stage/lib` is the directory containing the libraries and `boost_filesystem` the file name of the library without the beginning `lib` (modify those two as appropriate).

The .a file you're trying to link is the wrong one... the library should have no extension.

Answer (score 4):

Hi Following is the full procedure to add boost to cmake/make file. This answer is specially developed for the novice programmer in cpp.

If you want to add the boost library support with help of Makefile you need to specify library path (with -L option) and libraries (with -l option).

*-L path/to/the/libraries*
*-l llibrary*

**Now how to find path to libraries **

**Following is the trick:**

1. Open terminal and fire command

   > $ locate boost > libboost.txt
   >
   > $ gedit libboost.txt
2. This command opens a text file which contains all boost library paths.
3. Now find ("ctr+F") **libboost**, which highlights the library files of boost with extension .a and .so in this text file.
4. Copy the path in which this **.so** files are present.

   eg: If .so file present as on **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so**

   then specify path as : **-L /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/**

**Now how to find respective library?**

1. This depends on what boost functionalities/modules you are using

   **for example:** If you are using boost threading, you will require following libraries

   **libboost_filesystem.so**

   **libboost_thread.so**

   **libboost_system.so**
2. Add above libraries as follows with -l option:

   **-l lboost_filesystem**

   **-l lboost_thread**

   **-l lboost_system**

***Hope this will helps you, further If there is more easy way, please suggest***

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the boost libraries to the linking phase (the accesstimer target line) and not to the compilation phase (where only the include path is needed).