# boost makefile on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, boost, makefile

I'd like to use boost regex library and created a very short program to test my makefile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main() {

    regex exp("test");

    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Here is my makefile (I've got the boost includes from this thread [Including boost libraries in make files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305530/including-boost-libraries-in-make-files))

```
EXEC = main
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
HEADERS = $(wildcard *.h*)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(EXEC)

main: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

%.o: %.cpp $(HEADERS)
    g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include -c $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

When I compile my program a get the following error message:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include -c main.cpp -o main.o
g++ -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt main.o -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

What is missing?
I've installed boost with homebrew under Mac OS X 10.8.

Comment: It might be worth noting that Apple's implementation of the STL includes the C++11 [STL regular expressions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a link to the boost_regex_mt library

-lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt

In your makefile...

```
main: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/lib -lboost_regex-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_thread-mt     $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)
```